# HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient: Difference between 'basic' and 'stealth'?

Tags: configuration, onion-services, anonymity, security, server-administration

http://expyuzz4wqqyqhjn.onion/docs/tor-manual.html#HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient

> The auth-type can either be 'basic' for a general-purpose authorization protocol or 'stealth' for a less scalable protocol that also hides service activity from unauthorized clients.

Where can I find documentation on the `HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient` directive? "hides service activity" seems a little vague. What service activity and how is it hidden? Pros and cons to `basic` vs `stealth`?